# I need help on how to make an insert in sql server from node js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, asp.net-web-api, bootstrap-4

My question is how can I send the driver of my web api to make an insert to my database from node js ?, the web api is in visual studio and the node js in visual studio code. An acquaintance says that with a request I can do it, but I am very confused on how it should be done. If anyone can help I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  database: "mydb"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  var sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ('Company Inc', 'Highway 37')";
  con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 record inserted");
  });
});
```

Then simply run the file from the terminal. I know on lunix it's `$ node file.js`

Comment: but I'm using sql server, not mysql, and the connection and procedures, I have them in the web visual studio api

Comment: It should be the same thing, I think.

Comment: the professor said that the information should be sent in this way: html> Javascript> Node.js> Web Api> SQL

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: In your terminal, if you type **node C:\Users\Me\Documents\** then the name of your js document, it will run the insert.

Comment: Is that in the node js I have the html and its respective javascript, and the html has the boxes to write the information, of those boxes is the information that I have to take for my procedure from my database, but the database does not I use directly from code, I have the database and the procdures in the web api hosted in visual studio, while the node js I have it hosted in visual code

Answer (score 0):

if you are using sql server, you can use tedious:

```
    const Request = require('tedious').Request;
    const Connection = require('tedious').Connection;

    const DB = {
      async connect() {
    const config = {
      userName: your username,
      password: your password,
      server: your host,
      options: {
        port: port,
        database: database,
        rowCollectionOnRequestCompletion: true,
        rowCollectionOnDone: true,
      },
    };
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const connection = new Connection(config);
      connection.on('connect', (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(`connect error: ${err.message}`);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(connection);
        }
      });
    });
  },
  async request(sql) {
    const connection = await DB.connect();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.execSql(new Request(sql, (error, rowCount, rows) => {
        connection.close();
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve({
            rowCount,
            rows
          });
        }
      }));
    });
  },
};

module.exports = DB;
```

Comment: If I use sql server, but I do not do anything from the node js, I have a connection between the node js and the web api, it is assumed that in the node js I send everything from the web api, not from sql server directly

Comment: I must send call the procedures and the database from node, but my database is in the web api of visual studio

Comment: I have an example, but it will not let me upload the code